# How do I only show text in a certain cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a populated array which I can display in the tableview, but I want to hide 3 of the cells text (out of 7 cells). I know the below code is wrong, but in this case I only want to show the text in cell 0.

`cell.animal.text[0] = animalarray[0]
cell.animal.hidden = true`

Comment: do you want the cell to appear if the text is empty? Please also update your codes.

Comment: Yes I want the cell to exist, I have a set number of cells (7)

Comment: Cell for row at index path - if the cell is one of the cells you don't want text then don't add text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't have codes, I can only use words to describe how it should be done.

1. You need to have an array of the unwanted text that you do not want to show.
2. Inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you need to have a for loop, to go through the `animalarray`, and within the for loop, have an if-else statement to check whether if(unwantedtext == animalarray), then `cell!.textLabel.text = " "`

You need to show me codes for me to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna try to help you in Objective C, hopefully I can make the logic so clear the language difference doesn't matter.

Generally you are telling the TableView what to print for each cell in the below delegate method in your ViewController.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLable.text = animalArray[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

This is where you will decided which index in the animalArray you do or do not want to print.  If your requirement is a static the simplest is to hardcode the the blocking.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(!(indexPath.row == self.indexIDontWantToPrint)) {
        cell.textLable.text = animalArray[indexPath.row];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

If the indexes you do not want to print is dynamic and submitted to you by say an array.
You need to replace `if(!(indexPath.row == self.indexIDontWantToPrint))` with checking if indexPath.row is inside the array of indexes you are to ignore.

NSArray has a handy `containsObject` method you can use to check if the array contains the current index the tableView wants to print.  Be careful of the type difference of indexPath.row is NSInteger while NSArray needs to carry NSNumber for simple numeric numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more efficient logic than jo3birdtalk

1) Instead of having a extra array, you can creat an Object which contains a string & Bool.Add these objects  in `animalarray`

2) Get the object from array at indexpath & check
if(animal.isShow == YES),if Yes show the text else hide label Or set blank string whatever you required

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
 Animal * animal = animalArray[indexPath.row];
     if(animal.isShow == YES)
    {
         show the text
     }else
    {
        hide label Or set blank string whatever you requered
    } 

    return cell;
}
```